# Help to identify this song from "Richard Pryor Omit the Logic" documentary

Tags: identify-this-song, instrumental

In the documentary "Richard Pryor: Omit the Logic", exactly 2 minutes before the credits start, there is a slow, calm instrumental that plays over an image of a newspaper with the news of Pryor's death.

The song can be listened at this time of the documentary: [Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qw3WpoarHgA&feature=youtu.be&t=4750), 
[Alternate link](https://youtu.be/3NdA8XRjhQk?t=1h9m40s)

It is when the documentary is about to end and it talks about Richard Pryor´s death. The song continues through a GENIUS piece of monologue.

I already tried to find it looking through the songs which are enumerated at the credits. And also with Shazam, but no luck.

Comment: This is blocked in my country (USA); is there another link that you've found?

Comment: I have the same problem with the blocked link, and the watchable version I saw didn't respond to that timestamp. Can you describe the musical qualities of the song, and also give us some more detail to locate the same scene on a different stream of the video?

Comment: @Richard yes, i have found this link too: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dohXLAR5dHI&feature=youtu.be&t=5277

Comment: @Rober Also blocked in the US. It's just not in the stars for me to help :-) Best of luck!

Comment: @ChrisSunami ok, the timestamp doesn´t work... This scene is exactly 2 minutes before the end credits start. The scene starts with the image of a newspaper telling the news about Richard Pryor´s dead.

Comment: It also can be found at https://yts.ag/movie/richard-pryor-omit-the-logic-2013 via torrent. I know nobody will want to download it probably... And specially just for answer a question.. But hey I take advantage of this message for recommend it. You won´t regret!

Comment: Ah, sorry @ChrisSunami, but i don´t know very well how to describe the song.. I can tell you that it is instrumental. It´s a slow and calm song. I can´t say what instruments can be heard, sorry for that.

Comment: I edited the comments into the question, and added an alternate link that works for me.  It sounds to be electric guitar and maybe a little organ, it has a jazzy R&B feel.  I thought I maybe heard voices singing non-lexical vocables at one point --"oohs."

Comment: @ChrisSunami, thank so much for your collaboration. Really appreciated!

Comment: The music score for that documentary was done by [Mocean Worker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mocean_Worker).  So it may be by him. Nothing on his [Soundcloud channel](https://soundcloud.com/mocean-worker) matches it.

Comment: Hmm very interesting clue @Angst, thank you! Unfortunately i couldn´t find the song either. I also looked for it in youtube, but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adam Dorn aka Mocean: Richard Pryor - Omit The Logic Score

Track #6 - Richard Dies

[Listen here](https://octave.is/moceanworker/album/richard-pryor-omit-the-logic-score-highlights)